# ScrollView не загружает все элементы

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-scrollview

При загрузке моего приложения поле ScrollView изначально скрыто, но при загрузке данных с инета, ProgressBar скрывается, а ScrollView

Но вот проблема, (раньше все было нормально) при запуске на устройте не загружаются две последние кнопки "Настройки" и "Выход" при скролле показывает, что дальше скролить некуда, помогите

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment(), IUpdateUser {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentProfileBinding
    private lateinit var mainExit: IMainExit
    private lateinit var scrooll: IScrooll

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        mainExit = context as IMainExit
        scrooll = context as IScrooll
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.viewmodel!!.liveData.observeForever { user ->
            if (user != null) {
                if (user.isBan){
                    binding.exitBan.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.ban.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.loadingProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    scrooll.isScrollPager(false)
                    return@observeForever
                }
                Log.i("User",user.toString())
                binding.field.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.loadingProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE

                binding.viewmodel?.updateUser()
                binding.editAge.text = binding.viewmodel?.ageString()
                binding.editSex.text = binding.viewmodel?.sexString()
                binding.id.text =
                    "Id: ${binding.viewmodel?.user!!.id}"
                if (binding.viewmodel?.user!!.height != null) {
                    binding.editHeight.text = binding.viewmodel?.user!!.height.toString() + " СЃРј"
                }
                if (binding.viewmodel?.user!!.weight != null) {
                    binding.editWeight.text = binding.viewmodel?.user!!.weight.toString() + " РєРі"
                }
            }
        }

        binding.setting.setOnClickListener {
            SettingDialogFragment().show(childFragmentManager,"setting")
        }

        binding.exit.setOnClickListener {
            binding.viewmodel?.exit()

            mainExit.exit()
        }

        binding.exitBan.setOnClickListener {
            binding.viewmodel?.exit()

            mainExit.exit()
        }

        binding.update.setOnClickListener {
            ProfileUpdateDialogFragment.newInstance(this, binding.editHeight.text.toString().replace(" СЃРј",""),binding.editWeight.text.toString().replace(" РєРі","")).show(childFragmentManager,"update")
        }

    }

    override fun update(height: String, weight: String) {
        if (height == "") {
            binding.viewmodel?.user!!.height = null
            binding.editHeight.text = ""
        }
        else{
            binding.viewmodel?.user!!.height = height.toInt()
            binding.editHeight.text = "$height СЃРј"
        }
        if (weight == ""){
            binding.viewmodel?.user!!.weight = null
            binding.editWeight.text = ""
        }
        else {
            binding.viewmodel?.user!!.weight = weight.toInt()
            binding.editWeight.text = "$weight РєРі"
        }
        binding.viewmodel?.updateUserBase()
    }
}
```

xml

```
    <layout>
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.io.unknow.viewmodel.fragment.ProfileViewModel"/>
    </data>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ui.fragment.ProfileFragment"
    style="@style/background">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progresbar_custom" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ban"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Пользователь забанен"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/textView"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exitBan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@color/steel_gray"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_exit_to_app_24"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="start|center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_pink"
        android:text="@string/exit"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/background_item"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:elevation="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/id"
           style="@style/textView"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>

    </Toolbar>

<ScrollView
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            style="@style/background_item"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            style="@style/background_item"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blockone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sex_age"
            style="@style/background_dialog_title"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sex"
            style="@style/MarginProfile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sex"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/blockone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/MarginProfile"
            android:text="@string/age"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sex" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editSex"
                style="@style/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/sex"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sex" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editAge"
                style="@style/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/age"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/age" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        style="@style/background_item"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blocktwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/height_weight_local"
            style="@style/background_dialog_title"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/height"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/height"
            style="@style/MarginProfile"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/blocktwo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/weight"
            style="@style/MarginProfile"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/height" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/local"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/local"
            style="@style/MarginProfile"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/weight"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weight"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/update"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_create_24"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/blocktwo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editHeight"
            style="@style/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text='@{viewmodel.user.height == null? "" : viewmodel.user.height + @string/cm}'
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/height"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/height" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editWeight"
            style="@style/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text='@{viewmodel.user.weight == null? "" : viewmodel.user.weight + @string/kg}'
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/weight"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/weight" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            style="@style/background_item"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/textView"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/setting"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/textView"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/setting"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_exit_to_app_24"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="@string/exit"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

[[image: xml file]
[[image: Как выглядит при запуске]

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста разметку экрана полностью и код скрытия/показа контейнеров

Comment: Сделал, вот оно

Comment: Просто совет: нажатие Ctrl-Alt-L в студии производит автоматическое выравнивание кода, что сильно облегчает его чтение

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код фрагмента. В верстке я ошибок не вижу

Comment: Отправил код фрагмента

Comment: Чертовщина какая-то. Попробуйте на другом девайсе / эмуляторе.

Comment: Попробуйте временно убрать все кроме ScrollView из разметки. Мне кажется, что оно просто не влезает на экран